# Is there a way to go from the end to the start of a list while slicing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, slice

I don't mean reversing, but slicing the last few elements, but then if the length of the slice goes further than the length of the list, it carries on from the start.

For example:

`a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

Then if the slice starts at index 4 and is 5 elements long, the output is:

`[5, 6, 1, 2, 3]`

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: @Jab That's not particularly programatic...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well if you want you can use [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) and [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) this way it will wrap around to the start if the slice goes past the end of the list.

```
from itertools import cycle, islice

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
start, length = 4, 5

print(list(islice(cycle(a), start, start+length)))
```

Result:

```
[5, 6, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you ? `n` is the index to slice the list

```
n=4
print(a[n:] + a[:n-1])
```

Results as follow: `[5, 6, 1, 2, 3]`

Comment: The OP asked about using a length as well as a starting index.

Comment: You don't need to work with the length, try to set `n` more than the length of the list and it will work as well

Comment: I'm not talking about the length of the whole list. I mean, they wanted a length to the slice. They gave an example where the original list was length 6 but they only sliced out 5 elements of it (2 at the end and 3 at the start).

Answer (score 0):

You could write a little helper function to do this for you:

```
def my_slice(lst, start, length):
    end = start + length
    if end <= len(lst):
        return lst[start:end]
    else:
        end -= len(lst)
        return lst[start:] + lst[:end]
```